# How to disable title tooltips! (was: How to get element behind event target in Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, tooltip, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I have an element positioned on top of another element, how do I ignore the click capture of the top element and pass it to the one below it?

```
$('a[title]').each(function (index) {
    $(this).after('&lt;div class="overlay" style="position:absolute;background:url(../Images/space.gif);width:100px;height:100px;top:0;left:0;z-index:300"></div>')
})
```

The reason is because this bit of code is preventing the title tooltip from popping-up. The hover pseudo-class still works on the link behind it because it is attached to the element containing them both, like so:

```
li:hover a { ... }
```

Comment: looks like all your links have an element with the same `id` *overlay* on top of them...

Answer (score 0):

Please post a sample markup we can work with. Normally you just attach the event handler to the element you want, I don't understand what is the problem you are experiencing.

**EDIT** 
If I understand correctly this is some sort of tooltip and you want the user to pass on the click event. For a start, you can't use  id="overlay" in a loop, because ids need to be unique.  A simple way would be to create an event handler using .bind for pre-1.7 jquery, or on for 1.7

```
$('a[title]').each(function (index, el) {
      var $tooltip = $( '<div id="overlay-' + index  + '" />' ) 
                         //let JQuery create the CSS instead of using a style tag
                         .css({ position   : "absolute"
                              , background : "url(../Images/space.gif)"
                              , width   : 100
                              , height  : 100
                              , top     : 0
                              , left    : 0
                              , zIndex  : 300
                             })
                         //attach click handler to div
                         .on( 'click', function( e ){
                               $( el ).trigger( 'click' );
                            });
      $(this).after( $tooltip );
})
```

Comment: mmm... sorry, I still can't work out why are you trying to do what you are trying to do. You have a bunch of links and you are attaching an empty HTML string after each of them? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize the code wasn't displayed right... putting a transparent block on top of the links with title attributes.

Comment: That's awesome, but I keep getting an error that there is no trigger function.

Comment: sorry my bad - try again changed to $( el ).trigger( 'click' );

Comment: Well then I can't help without seen the whole page, sorry

Comment: Okay, figured it out, the document click handler was messing it up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

looks like all your links have an element with the same `id` *overlay* on top of them.

remove the `id` and add a `class` to your transparent block `div`.

then add a `click` event to this `class` doing what you want with the `parent` element.

Comment: It's not actually a parent element that I'm targeting. It's a link with a div on top of it. I want the click event to pass through the div to trigger the link.

Answer (score 0):

-------*Solution*----------

```
 $('a[title]').each(function (index, el) {
    var $tooltip = $('<div class="overlay-' + index + '" />')
                         .css({
                            position: "absolute"
                            , background: "url('../Images/space.gif')"
                            , width: $(el).width()
                            , height: $(el).height()
                            , top: 0
                            , left: 0
                            , zIndex: 300
                            , border: "1px solid red"
                         })
                         .on('click', function (event) {
                             $(el).click();
                         });
    $(this).after($tooltip);
})
```

Comment: [Moved OPs solution from an edit  to a community wiki.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)